# Add Custom TiniMCE Buttons to the Second Line?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Does anyone know how can I add my custom TinyMCE buttons on Wordpress to the second line instead of the first one?

The problem is that I got more than 10, and they keep grouping to the right braking the Wordpress editor.

My solution would be to put some below, but I can't find any documentation pointing to that scenario.

The code I am using to add buttons to the first line with success is (part) of the following

```
 ed.addButton('example', {
     title : 'example.desc',
     image : '../jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/example/img/example.gif',
     onclick : function() {
        ed.windowManager.alert('Hello world!! Selection: ' + ed.selection.getContent({format : 'text'}));
     }
```

Any comment in the right direction will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Found my answer in this other answer here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13633/when-adding-buttons-to-the-tinymce-editor-how-do-i-make-them-wrap-to-the-next-li hope it helps someone.

Comment: Jordan, you should've posted that as an answer to the question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the hook:

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'add_my_tinymce_buttons' );
```

Use:

```
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'add_my_tinymce_buttons' );
```

Documentation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_buttons,_mce_buttons_2,_mce_buttons_3,_mce_buttons_4